# Python 3.xx : Classes in classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, subclassing

I need help for my python scripts. How to access my clock's function through Date's classes ?

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

class Date(object):
    def date_today(self):
        now = date.today()
        print (now)

class Time(Date):
    pass
    def clock(self):
        hr = datetime.now()
        hr_now = hr.hour
        print (hr_now)

cr_date = Date()
print (cr_date.date_today())
print (cr_date.date_today.clock())
```

i got an error --> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'clock'. What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Yes your Date class has no clock() function.

Comment: i got 2 classess, Date classes and Time Classes i just want to access the Time classes through Date classes, do you have any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

you can also add minute, second and other related functions in your time class. I hope it will help.

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

class Time():
    def clock(self):
        hr = datetime.now()
        hr_now = hr.hour
        return hr_now

class Date():
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = Time()

    def date_today(self):
        now = date.today()
        return now

    def clock(self):
        return self.time.clock()




cr_date = Date()

print(cr_date.date_today())
print(cr_date.clock())
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Harun so much. this is helpfull for me

Comment: what is this script cr_date.date_today.clock() means ? (in my previous script)

Comment: You don't have to call this way. In your question date_today() is a function and has no clock() function as attribute so it raise error.